# How to debug a sys.modules entry that gets overwritten?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to debug an issue that causes `sys.modules['numpy']` to get overwritten. I've added some print statements to `numpy.__init__`, and when I try to import numpy, I get this output:

```
numpy.__init__ running
id(sys.modules) = 89034704
id(sys.modules['numpy']) = 161528304
numpy.__init__ running
id(sys.modules) = 89034704
id(sys.modules['numpy']) = 177135864
```

Numpy has a number of circular imports, which should work as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/744071). But in my case, instead of getting the partially initialized numpy module from `sys.modules`, numpy gets imported again, and `numpy.__init__` gets executed a second time, leading to a crash.

**How can I instrument `sys.modules` to get some visibility into who is overwriting `sys.modules['numpy']` and when?** Normally I would write a dict subclass, but I don't think it's safe to change `sys.modules` to point to my own object. I tried overriding `sys.modules.__setattr__`, but that's a read-only attribute.

Context: I'm trying to debug [this issue](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/65#issuecomment-68964038) in PyCall, a Julia library. PyCall embeds a Python interpreter in a running Julia process, and delegates the import to `PyImport_ImportModule` from cpython. The problem above happens inside a single call to `PyImport_ImportModule`, so I hope this question should be answerable with knowledge of python / cpython, but without knowledge of Julia / PyCall.

Comment: I would first try to reproduce the error only in Python, without involving Julia (or, ideally, direct C API calls) at all.  Do you have example Python code that can do that?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778407/do-something-every-time-a-module-is-imported) suggests overriding `__import__` might work.  I suspect the problem is due to some sort of path mixup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BrenBarn for pointing me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778568/744071. The following worked for my purposes:

importhack.py:

```
import traceback

old_import = __import__

def my_import(module, *args, **kwargs):
    print "my_import({}) caused by:".format(module)
    traceback.print_stack()
    return old_import(module, *args, **kwargs)

__builtins__['__import__'] = my_import
```

Usage:

```
>>> import importhack
>>> import numpy
```

I believe the original problem in PyCall.jl was caused by calling `PyImport_ImportModule` before the Python interpreter was fully initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can change `sys.modules` from a plain `dict` to one that `prints` out assignments, e.g:

```
import sys
import traceback

class noisydict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('ASSIGNED: key={!r} value={!r} at:'.format(key, value))
        traceback.print_stack()
        return dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

sys.modules = noisydict(sys.modules)
```

This may or may not work if the overwriting happens in C code (such code may directly access the underlying `dict.__setitem__` rather than just do a `sys.modules[name] = newmodule` as Python code would) but it's worth a try!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help; I tried putting your code in a file `sysmoduleshack.py`. Then from the interpreter: `import sysmoduleshack; import numpy` prints nothing. I suspect you're right that the dict is modified from C code.

Comment: @cberzan, then your life gets harder -- and 100% dependent on the exact version of Python, which you don't mention (the importing system changes often).  At least try `python -v` to tell you exactly what's being imported up to the time of the crash you observe -- again, it's a start.

Comment: You forgot to `print` the "ASSIGNED" string you created.  But I think the `import` mechanism that modifies `sys.modules` does so at the C level, so I don't think this will work.  In fact, when I try it, it seems to prevent imported modules from getting into the new `sys.modules` at all.

Comment: Tx @BrenBarn for spotting my `thinko`, edited now to fix that.